# How can I start a udev-activated systemd user service on login?

Tags: systemd, udev, services, systemctl, autostart

I have a slightly convoluted setup that allows me to start a systemd user service (`launchpad-daemon.service`) when a USB device is plugged in, and stop it when the device is unplugged. It consists of the following udev rule:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="sound", ENV{ID_MODEL}=="Launchpad_Mini_MK3", ENV{SYSTEMD_USER_WANTS}+="launchpad-daemon.service"
```

and a user service configuration like the following:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/.../launchpad-daemon-start
ExecStopPost=/.../launchpad-daemon-stop
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/...

[Unit]
Description=Novation Launchpad daemon
StopWhenUnneeded=true
```

This works great when I plug/unplug the USB device while I'm logged in. Unfortunately, it does not work if I log in while the device is already plugged in – `systemctl --user status` reports that the service is inactive unless I start it by hand or replug the device. Usually I would start a service on login by setting something like `WantedBy=graphical-session.target`, but that will presumably start it regardless of whether the USB device is available.

How can I get the service to autostart when I log in *if and only if* the USB device is plugged in?

Answer (score 0):

You could add

```ini
[Unit]
ConditionPathExists=/dev/path/to/mydevice 
# e.g. /dev/disk/by-id/usb-Ut165_USB2FlashStorage_0805090215d3a7-0
```

in addition to `WantedBy=sometarget.target` to only start the service if the specified device file exists (i.e., the device is plugged).

This doesn't work for a wildcard service though.